# fineract API Post recurringdepositaccount not working and It is not also covered in the fineract documentation

Tags: java, c#, apache-fineract

fineract Post recurringdepositaccount api in postman  responds with the error message:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1568640270686,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
    "message": null,
    "path": "/fineract-provider/api/v1/recurringdepositaccounts"
}
```

Here is my request body:

```
{
  "clientId": 67,
  "productId": 6,
  "locale": "en",
  "dateFormat": "dd MMMM yyyy",
  "submittedOnDate": "13 September 2019",
  "depositPeriodFrequencyId":1,
  "depositPeriod":1,
  "recurringFrequencyType":1,
  "recurringFrequency":1,
  "mandatoryRecommendedDepositAmount":1000,
  "isCalendarInherited":false,
  "preClosurePenalApplicable":false,
  "isMandatoryDeposit":true,
   "allowWithdrawal": false,
   "adjustAdvanceTowardsFuturePayments":false
}
```

Comment: HTTP Error 500 is a standard error for any request.  If you have a working application use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare first request of working against non working.  500 indicates an authentication error which usually means the TLS is failing and/or certificate is bad.

Comment: I don't know fineract, but as mentioned by @jdweng above, `500` is a standard error code when something goes wrong at the server-side (hence the error `Internal Server Error`). Based on the exception `java.lang.NullPointerException` and message `null`, it seems something went wrong in the Java part of the code. I'm not sure if you can somehow access/debug that Java code, or have a log file stating the line number where this NulPointerException is occurring? Or is the Java server-side a black box?

Comment: Found this:
https://demo.openmf.org/api-docs/apiLive.htm#rdaccounts
Your code triggers an NPE, so if you are running this yourself, try hooking the server to a debugger to step through. If you have no control over the server, perhaps you're missing a required parameter?

Comment: @ThomasTimbul, I am running the server locally myself. I am also suspecting a missing required parameter but the api documentation: demo.openmf.org/api-docs/apiLive.htm#rdaccounts does not cover post recurringdepositaccount and if it a missing parameter it will respond with a custom error message indicating the missing parameter ...

Comment: @SukurujuShabangu it does if you scroll down (quite a bit). `Mandatory fields: clientId or groupId, productId, submittedOnDate, depositPeriod, depositPeriodFrequencyId, recurringFrequency, recurringFrequencyType, depositAmount,isCalendarInherited, mandatoryRecommendedDepositAmount`.

You appear to be missing `depositAmount`.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation I could find at https://demo.openmf.org/api-docs/apiLive.htm#rdaccounts
(scroll down beyond all the `GET` examples to get to the `POST` part) states the following mandatory fields:

```
clientId or groupId,
productId,
submittedOnDate,
depositPeriod,
depositPeriodFrequencyId,
recurringFrequency,
recurringFrequencyType,
depositAmount,
isCalendarInherited,
mandatoryRecommendedDepositAmount
```

Of these you appear to be missing `depositAmount`.

Comment: I did find it in the documentation but still responded with the same error message. My request body:{
  "clientId": "66",
  "productId": "9",
  "locale": "en",
  "dateFormat": "dd MMMM yyyy",
  "submittedOnDate": "13 September 2019",
  "depositPeriod":"1",
  "depositPeriodFrequencyId":"0",
  "depositAmount":"100",
  "isCalendarInherited":false,
  "recurringFrequency":"1",
  "recurringFrequencyType":"0",
  "mandatoryRecommendedDepositAmount":"100"
}

Comment: Then I'd strongly suggest step-debugging to find the problem. If the tool allows, set an Exception break point so that the debugger suspends once it hits the NPE.